# unknown column in 'P001' where clause

Tags: mysql

I trying to delete an entry from a table in mysql the table is for publications This is the table.

```
CREATE TABLE publication(pub_id VARCHAR(4) NOT NUll,
                         price DECIMAL(3, 2) NOT NULL,
                         name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                         frequency INTEGER(10) NOT NULL,
                         PRIMARY KEY(pub_id) );
```

This is the table with added entries

[image]

The query i'm using is

```
Delete from publication where pub_id = P001;
```

I get an error "Unknown column 'P001' in where clause"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use quotes, it will try to find a column|other object named `P001`. Try

```
delete from publication where pub_id = 'P001';
```

Comment: Ahh I see. That worked. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to see it worked. Remember to mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question, so others that end up here will know what's the answer.

Answer (score 1):

please check manual **Mysql**
correct:

```
Delete from publication where pub_id = 'P001';
```

check the manual and sintaxis [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html)